# How to apply conditional formatting formula in MS Excel using Pivot Table values?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I have a pivot table and I would like to use conditional formating to visualize better whether Actual is greater or less than LY (Similar to the below).

I have tried using GetPivotData in Conditional Formatting but Excel doesn't seem to like the formula.

This has to be done to all "Actual" values for "Department" and "Month" divided by all respective LY values for Department and Month.

i.e. Actual Amount/LY Amount for all Departments and Months

Any ideas on how to go about this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the value field to the "Values" area twice.
2. Select one of the value column and go to "Field Settings" to "Show Value As" Difference From LY
3. Select one of the value in the "difference" column, add new Conditional Formatting rule
4. Play with the rule details as show below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. However, this would be on a different row, correct? So, I'd have a variance icon, revenue, and an LY row?

Comment: First row = variance icon + revenue, Second row = LY, just like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z635c.png)

Comment: Could it be done with shading instead of icons? The rules are different. 

Something I was looking into was: Showing only 'Actuals' shading the cell according to LY values. 

Eg. Less than 10% variance - Green
10% - 30% Amber
More than 30% Red

Comment: There's no direct way to do what you want. To do so in a "cheating" way, create a "Calculated Item" with name = `Actual<space>` and formula as `= ABS((Actual-LY)/LY/10)+Actual` (or whatever fit your definition of "variance"). Then, conditional-format this item by 3 formula as `=MOD([field location, no "$"]*1000,1000)<10` with "<10" replaced by your desired ranges vs colors.  Then, change the number format to show no decimal place. Hide "Actual" and "LY" rows.  WARNING:This is for DISPLAY purpose ONLY (because there're actually extra decimal places)

Comment: To explain, the above just to "embedded" the variance to the actual value in order to do the formatting.